# Is it possible to make a Web Component List with undetermined number of slot?

Tags: javascript, html, listview, web-component

I know it can be achieved using Javascript by manually separate the slot elements and put them into the DOM tree but I wonder if it's supported within the box. Something like this:

```html
<my-element>
    <div slot="items">Item 1</div>
    <div slot="items">Item 2</div>
    <div slot="items">...</div>
</my-element>
```

And the template should be like this:

```html
<div class="items">
    <div class="item"> <!-- Should be 1 item per slot -->
        <p>Something else</p>
        <slot name="items"></slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this only possible using `slotchange` and populate the items by Javascript? Is there any better solution, without Javascript or with less Javascript? Maybe there is an element similar to `slot` that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since **all** `slot="items"` will be slotted into `<slot name="items">` only with the `slotchange` Event can the Component Author determine what *happened*.

Note: *You* do not populate the items, the default slotting mechanism does; you can only remove items *after* they are slotted; but then your HTML above needs more info on *which* Item needs to be slotted.

Then the question remains, Why use multiple `slot="items"` at all then?? If a slot can take 1 item, then only assign 1 item

Imperative Slots might help out: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/blob/gh-pages/proposals/Imperative-Shadow-DOM-Distribution-API.md

#### Update, I misunderdstood OPs question

All he needs to do is:

**Create another Web Component: `<slotted-item slot="items"></slotted-item>`**

Comment: Sorry maybe my example wasn't clear enough. The problem is I don't want to just "stuff" them all in one place, but _for each_ item, there are additional surrounding context, like `<p>Something else</p>` or `<div>` wrapper as well. I guess it cannot be achieved without scripting.

Comment: Create another Web Component? ``<slotted-item slot="items"></slotted-item>``

Comment: Oops you are right lol. I can't believe I didn't think of this! Can you add that piece to your answer? I will mark it.

Comment: Maybe take inspiration from [my Dev.To post on UnknownElements](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c)